Why Sequelize migration create my table with only 1 foreing key instead of 2?
Im trying to make a intermediate table between 2 models, called User and Reminder.
The fact is everytime i try to migrate or create the table UserReminders I dont get 2 foreing keys, userId and reminderId, instead I only get ONE foreing key, which is reminderId.
This is what appears on my table on heidiSQL
I created a model on my backend called UserReminder and the migration of it for my database on HeidiSQL.
MODEL:
import { Model } from 'sequelize'

const loadModel = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class UserReminder extends Model {
    static associate (models) {
      // Un UserReminder pertenece a un usuario
      UserReminder.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'userId', onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
      // Un UserReminder pertenece a un recordatorio
      UserReminder.belongsTo(models.Reminder, { foreignKey: 'reminderId', onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
    }
  }

  UserReminder.init({
    userId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'Users',
        key: 'id'
      },
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      onUpdate: 'CASCADE'
    },
    reminderId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'Reminders',
        key: 'id'
      },
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      onUpdate: 'CASCADE'
    },
    createdAt: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW
    },
    updatedAt: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'UserReminder',
    tableName: 'UserReminders',
    timestamps: true,
    indexes: [
      {
        unique: true,
        fields: ['userId', 'reminderId']
      }
    ]
  })

  return UserReminder
}

export default loadModel

MIGRATION:
'use strict'
/** @type {import('sequelize-cli').Migration} */
module.exports = {
  async up (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('UserReminders', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      userId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
          model: 'Users',
          key: 'id'
        },
        onDelete: 'CASCADE'
      },
      reminderId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
          model: 'Reminders',
          key: 'id'
        },
        onDelete: 'CASCADE'
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.fn('now')
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.fn('now')
      }
    })

    await queryInterface.addConstraint('UserReminders', {
      fields: ['userId', 'reminderId'],
      type: 'unique',
      name: 'unique_user_reminder'
    })
  },

  async down (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('UserReminders')
  }
}

I was expecting to have 1 primary key called id, 2 foreing keys userId and reminderId, and one unique key compound (userId, reminderId). But i got the things I said but with only ONE foreing key (reminderId) instead of 2.
